# Is pipeline as code feature available when the repository selected is "Other Git" in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

We intend to consume pipelines written in yaml file in azure devops, is this feature available when the repository type selected is "Other Git".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No. That's why it doesn't have a "YAML" option next to it. The options that support YAML say "YAML" next to them. The ones that don't support YAML don't have that.